# How to store single result in variable and reuse it in a query (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, scripting

I have a query like

```
SELECT id FROM xyz WHERE ...;
```

which has a more or less complex WHERE clause and returns exactly one row with one column (ID). I need this ID for several later queries in a script. 
So my goal was to reuse this result in a variable but I don´t come to a solution which works.

Joining this query would not be a good option in this circumstance. So is it possible to tell Oracle to store this single result in a variable and use this variable to build up new queries - explicitly to use in in the conditional clause of other queries?

If so, perhaps somebody could post a simple example - most simple perhaps would be sth. like

```
SELECT :VARIABLE FROM DUAL
```

Comment: What is executing your script? SQL*Plus?

Comment: Currently I´m using Toad for Oracle - but could use Sqlplus too. This shouldn´t make any difference...

Comment: Why do you think "this shouldn´t make any difference"? SQL*Plus [has it's own variables](http://www.orafaq.com/node/515) that are quite distinct from the database (and of course therefore can't be used in Toad)

Comment: or do you mean that you are looking for a solution that can be run in SQL*Plus *or* Toad?

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't make any difference, but it does.

Comment: Oh ... I always thought it doesn´t matter whether I execute a script in Toad or in SqlPlus. This might be an explanation why the examples on the net didn´t work for me. I´ll try this out...

Answer (score 2):

For Toad, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1948461/533832) answer on SO:

> I think this will accomplish what you want.  You can declare a bind variable, insert a value into it, and then use it in future statements.
>
> ```
> variable l_var varchar2(1);
>
> begin
>   select dummy
>     into :l_var
>     from dual;
> end; 
>
> select *
> from dual
> where dummy = :l_var;
> ```

Comment: TOAD seems to support at least some SQL*Plus syntax. But TOAD is more forgiving with missing `;` and `/` as well as comments at the end of lines (which will cause the statement to be ignored in SQL*Plus, but TOAD will execute it).

Comment: In other words you can't guarantee your script will have the same action in both :)

Comment: You can, but you must be very careful to use the syntax supported by both SQL*Plus and TOAD! And test, test, test in both tools.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a difference... SQL*Plus can use variables, but they're a SQL*Plus feature and you can just grab that block of code and pass it to an Oracle backend to execute (like you could with a Transact SQL block for example).

You can choose between using bind variables in SQL*Plus as follows:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/use_vars.html

Or use SQL*Plus's own variables with DEFINE and COLUMN commands:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/new_value.html

If you really need the code to be executable in other environments, you will probably have to go down the PL/SQL route.